# rsync exclude-from not skipping some items in the list

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci, rsync

I have an rsync command like this:
`rsync -avz --exclude-from 'exclude-list.txt' -r /source/ destination`

the `exclude-list.txt` looks like this:

```
.git
src
config.js
.gitlab-ci.yml
.gitignore
local-*
```

All the listed files and directories are in the same directory as the `exclude-list.txt` file.

So, the `.git`, `src` and `config.js` are skipped over and not copied (like I want), but the rest of the items are still copied. What's wrong with my syntax? (`local-*` is supposed to be a wildcard to skip all files beginning with `local-`).

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: @John1024 strange. I'm doing this with gitlab-ci deploy job over ssh to a prod env. would any of that even matter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with gitlab-ci.  I see no reason why ssh should make a difference.  Since you are doing this cross-machine, I would suggest checking for encoding or line-ending issues with the `exclude-list.txt` file.

Comment: I would expect the assumption of @John1024 to be right. Did you fill ther `exclude-list.txt` by copy/paste? Doing this, you often copy also invisible chars that rsync will confuse. Using `cat -e exclude-list.txt`will show you line endings and invisible chars.

Comment: thanks guys. I'll look into it. I did fill it out by typing though. No copy-paste.

Comment: somehow it was not working before but now it's working. I did not change anything :P

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue with `rsync` on `Puppy Linux` and in my case 2 things got it to run fine

- the  file paths in `exclude.txt` are always relative to *source directory.*

  ```
       e.g. /src/f_a/fileA , /src/fileB  in exclude file will be 
       f_a/fileA
       fileB
  ```
- if there are spaces or escape characters then at least in my case it did not respect them. So it just reads the path  as in a matching sense to see if it aligns as a pattern without interpreting your escapes

  ```
       e.g. /src/program files if written as 
            /src/program\ files or 
            /src/'program files'
  ```

the latter 2 will not be matched and folder will not be excluded. Only the 1st one works

- the path of the `exclude.txt` can be given as absolute or relative